# Inputting .val() from list in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

I'm trying to get information from a list(listDIV) to show up in my form (formDIV), I'm getting the information from a database using JSON. I'm only getting the error  "Database erro, please select something else." in my textarea field, which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my PHP.

HTML & JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#productList").change(function() {

    var action = $("#productForm").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        id: $('#productList').val(),
        name: $("#name").val(),
        price: $("#price").val(),
        img: $("#img").val(),
        description: $("#description").val()
    };

var id="something";
    $.getJSON("getProduct.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
            case 0: $("#name").value(data.data.prodName);
            break;
            default: $("#description").html("Database error, please select something else.");
            break;
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>  
</head><body>

<div id="listDIV">
<select id="productList" name="productList" size="8">
    <option value="123" class="prodID">Terminator Series</option>
    <option value="124" class="prodID">2001 A Space Odyssey</option>
    <option value="125" class="prodID">Serenity</option>
    <option value="126" class="prodID">Alien Quadrilogy</option>
    <option value="127" class="prodID">12 Monkeys</option>
    <option value="128" class="prodID">Final Fantasy</option>
</select>
</div><div id="formDIV">
<form id="productForm" action="getProduct.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="img" placeholder="Image" /><br />
    <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

PHP (getProduct.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('productDB') or
    die ('Can\'t use database: ' . mysql_error());

// retval: 0 - login ok, 1 - login failed, 2 - internal error
$json = array("retval" => 2, "data" => NULL, "debug" => "");

 $id=json_decode($_REQUEST['id']);
 $prodID=$id->id;

$sql="SELECT * FROM productTB WHERE prodID=" . $prodID;


$json['debug'] .= "SQL query was: ".$sql."\n";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    $json['debug'] .= "SQL query failed\n";
    $json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
die(json_encode($json));
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    $json['retval'] = 0;
    $json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
    $json['retval'] = 1;
}
$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($json);
```

Table Structure for my DB:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `productTB`
--

CREATE TABLE `productTB` (
`prodID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`prodName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`prodPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`prodDesc` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`prodImg` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`prodID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Access the php directly in your browser.  If it works there, then your problem is in jquery, if it doesn't work there, the problem is with your php/mysql

Comment: You have an extra commma in your `form_data`   `description: $("#description").val(),` <---

Comment: in getproduct.php fie.. check last line echo json_encode($json);
is working or not?

Comment: I removed the comma. And this is what I get frmo the getProduct.php: "{"retval":1,"data":null,"debug":"SQL query was: SELECT * FROM productTB WHERE prodID=''\nOther output: "}"

Comment: try echo $sql...and copy that line and run it in your phpmyadmin. check whether query executing correctly.

Comment: echo $sql is telling me that prodID is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the variable.. not the string

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM productTB WHERE prodID=" . $prodID;
```

Though I would recommend using preparedstatements

**EDIT:**

You are not passing `ID` to your php page..  Here's what you can access - These are what you are passing to your PHP -

Change

```
var form_data = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    price: $("#price").val(),
    img: $("#img").val(),
    description: $("#description").val()
};
```

to

```
var form_data = {
    id: $('#productList').val(), // <-- pass the id
    name: $("#name").val(),
    price: $("#price").val(),
    img: $("#img").val(),
    description: $("#description").val()
};
```

You either need to Pass `ID` to the page or query to get the `ID` first from the DB.  Then you can use the ID in your query to get the results

Comment: @Phawkes check my update.  You are not passing ID so that's why there is no prod id showing up in your sql statement

Comment: @Phawkes yes..  That way you can access it in your php code.. But I think you want `$('#productList').val()`

Comment: You need to change `$prodID` to `$prodId` <--Notice little d -- in your sql statement

Comment: @Phawkes Actually.. why don't you just use `$id`

Comment: Is your SQL query actually correct now?  What does it look like?

Comment: We can hop in chat in a sec.. You can just erase `$prodID=$id->id;`.. then in the sql statement use `$id`

Comment: @Phawkes  Are you able to start a chat?  It keeps saying you don't have enough rep.  Anyways did changing it to $id help fix your SQL statement?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18258/discussion-between-phawkes-and-wirey)