# Updating Database through form w/ JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms

Continuation of my previous post.. [Inputting .val() from list in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962484/inputting-val-from-list-in-php) That part of the code is now working, now I need to be able to update & modify the text that is popping up.

The query is not receiving any content.

HTML & JS:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// Sends information into form - Works 
$("#productList").change(function() {

    var action = $("#productForm").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        id: $('#productList').val(),
        name: $("#name").val(),
        price: $("#price").val(),
        img: $("#img").val(),
        description: $("#description").val()
    };      
var id="something";
    $.getJSON("getProduct.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
            case 0: $("#name").value(data.data.prodName);
            break;
            default: $("#description").html("Database error, please select something else.");
            break;
        }
        });
    });
// End form information

$("#productForm").submit(function() {
    var action = $("#productForm").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        id: $('#productList').val(),
        name: $("#name").val(),
        price: $("#price").val(),
        img: $("#img").val(),
        description: $("#description").val()
    };      
var id="something";
    $.getJSON("modify.php",form_data,function(data){
        switch(data.retval){
            case 0: $("#status").html("Update successful!");
            break;
            case 1: $("#status").html("Unable to update!");
            break;
            default: $("#description").html("Database error, please try again.");
            break;
        }
        });
    });
});
</script>  
</head><body>

<div id="status"></div>
<div id="listDIV">
<select id="productList" name="productList" size="8">
    <option value="123" class="prodID">Terminator Series</option>
    <option value="124" class="prodID">2001 A Space Odyssey</option>
    <option value="125" class="prodID">Serenity</option>
    <option value="126" class="prodID">Alien Quadrilogy</option>
    <option value="127" class="prodID">12 Monkeys</option>
    <option value="128" class="prodID">Final Fantasy</option>
</select>
</div><div id="formDIV">
<form id="productForm" action="getProduct.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price" /><br />
    <input type="text" id="img" placeholder="Image" /><br />
    <textarea id="description" placeholder="Description"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" id="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

PHP (modify.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root') or 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('productDB') or
    die ('Can\'t use database: ' . mysql_error());

// retval: 0 - login ok, 1 - login failed, 2 - internal error
$json = array("retval" => 2, "data" => NULL, "debug" => "");

 $id=json_decode($_REQUEST['id']);
 $prodName=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
 $prodPrice=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['price']);
 $prodImg=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['img']);
 $prodDesc=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']);

$sql = "UPDATE productTB SET prodName=".$prodName.", prodPrice=".$prodPrice.", prodDesc=".$prodDesc.", prodImg=".$prodImg." WHERE prodID=".$id.";";


$json['debug'] .= "SQL query was: ".$sql."\n";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    $json['debug'] .= "SQL query failed\n";
    $json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
die(json_encode($json));
}
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
    $json['retval'] = 0;
    $json['data'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
} else {
    $json['retval'] = 1;
}
$json['debug'] .= "Other output: ". ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo json_encode($json);
```

Table Structure for my DB:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `productTB`
--

CREATE TABLE `productTB` (
`prodID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`prodName` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`prodPrice` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`prodDesc` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`prodImg` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`prodID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Two things, first you don't need to JSON decode every value, just the one value that you get. Second your mysql queries are terrible... you use the request method and add it directly to a mysql query. I can delete your entire database using just javascript. I'd suggest you look at PDO or sprintf your queries.

Comment: Did you try any debugging tool to see where is the problem actually? You can use FireBug or Chrome developer tool for that.

Comment: yea, tried firebug, but click event never fires so no indicator. I think the: `$("#makecollapsible .makecollapsibleul .productForm").on("click", ".submit", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
 });` is the problem, but don't thing I have it formatted right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preventDefault of form submit action.  Since none of your form elements have a `name` attribute.  It's posting without any parameters.  That's the reason why your SQL statement isn't receiving anything.

You need

```
$("#productForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // your code goes here
}
```